# Where does docker store it's temp files during extraction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

Before you chastise me for having a 12 GB image, know that it's the only way we can handle this specific scenario and still automate the build process. When I'm done with this project, I'll put myself in timeout - I promise.

Now, I'm working on a project with Opsworks and I need to pull down that very large image I mentioned. However, unless we use the AWS console, we can't change the size of the root volume on the EC2 instance in Opsworks. So, I mount a 50 GB volume at `/var/lib/docker/` at startup. However, the Docker API is still saying that I'm running out of disk space (50 GB is much more than is necessary) during the image extraction. I'm guessing that docker is storing these temporary files somewhere other than in `/var/lib/docker/` but for the life of me, I can't figure out where.

Hell, if someone can come up with a way to increase the root volume size of an Opsworks EC2 instance without creating a custom image, that would be nice too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Docker will use `/var/lib/docker/tmp` for it's temporary directory. This can be overridden with the `DOCKER_TMP` environment variable for the docker daemon.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, but it appears that my issue is a bit more complicated than I initially thought. It's either a problem with the Docker API, the Docker cookbook for Chef, or an AWS issue (ECR, EC2, etc.). I'll be putting up another question shortly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Docker on Ubuntu and to needed to move the temporary directory to another drive to avoid thrashing the USB disk.

The [following method](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169) worked for me.

1. Stop docker
2. Move the directory and contents.
3. Create a symlink from the original location to the new one.
4. Start docker.